# iPhone SDK - MapKit CoreLocation - Make street address from latitude and longitude

Tags: iphone, mapkit, core-location

I have a problem in an app I am building.

I can retrieve the users latitude and longitude, however I need to convert those values into an `NSString` street address. ie. "123 Park Street, Sydney".

Any idea as to how I can create a street address from the coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation for `MKReverseGeocoder`.

**Edit**: As stated in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKReverseGeocoder/initWithCoordinate:), `MKReverseGeocoder` is deprecated in iOS 5.0. Use the `CLGeocoder` class instead ([documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLGeocoder/reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:), [example code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526541/clgeocoder-reversegeocodelocation-returns-kclerrordomain-error-9)).

Comment: Thanks, figured it all out. initWithCoordinate: does the trick :)