# CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation returns 'kCLErrorDomain error 9'

Tags: ios, core-location, reverse-geocoding

I'm developing an iOS app with reverse geocoding features according to this article: [geocoding tutorial](http://jonathanfield.me/jons-blog/clgeocoder-example.html)

But when I test like this on simulator, I get 'kCLErrorDomain error 9'. I've searched a lot and there are only error 0 or 1 not 9.

Here is my code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 80.0;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[[CLGeocoder alloc] init] autorelease];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.locationManager.location 
   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler: Completion Handler called!");

       if (error){
           NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);            
           return;

       }

       if(placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)

       {
           //do something   
           CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
           NSString *addressTxt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@,%@ %@", 
                                   [topResult subThoroughfare],[topResult thoroughfare],
                                   [topResult locality], [topResult administrativeArea]];
           NSLog(@"%@",addressTxt);
       }
   }];
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: The simulator returns error 8 now while I did nothing to my code.

Comment: CLLocationManager, CLGeocoder Will not work on simulator. It will display results only on debugging on Device or testing on device. On Simulator it will show error.

Comment: This works like a charm on my iPhone 4 device.  Thanks!

Comment: You must make sure you're simulating location in the simulator

Answer (score 18):

The Core Location error codes are [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010237-CH2-SW2).

Code values 8, 9, and 10 are:

```
kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult,
kCLErrorGeocodeFoundPartialResult,
kCLErrorGeocodeCanceled
```

Based on the code shown, the most likely reason you'd get error 8 is that it's trying to use `location` immediately after calling `startUpdatingLocation` at which time it might still be `nil`.

It usually takes a few seconds to obtain the current location and it will most likely be `nil` until then (resulting in geocode error 8 or `kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult`).  I'm not sure what error code 9 means by "FoundPartialResult" but Apple's GeocoderDemo sample app treats both the same way (as "No Result").

Try moving the geocoding code (all the code after the `startUpdatingLocation` call) to the delegate method `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`.  The location manager will call that delegate method when it actually has a location and only then is it safe to use `location`.

There, after the geocoding is successful (or not), you may want to call `stopUpdatingLocation` otherwise it will try geocoding every time the user location is updated.

You may also want to check the accuracy (`newLocation.horizontalAccuracy`) and age (`newLocation.timestamp`) of the received location before trying to geocode it.

Comment: Thank you. After move my code according to your advice, it shows error 9 even if I set my CCLocation as `CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:37.78583400 longitude:-122.40641700];`. Maybe there is something error on the simulator, I'm going to test it on my device.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I mixed up the longitute and latitude when creating the location. Thought I'd add this as something for people to check.